# CS50 Week 4 Memory, how does fread know to move onto the next byte of the file?

Tags: c, cs50

The source that were reading from is a .txt file that says Hi. How would the loop know to read the next byte in memory?

since its reading and writing a byte one at a time

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

BYTE buffer;

while (fread(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 1, source))
{
    fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(BYTE), 1, destination);
}
```

Comment: the FILE struct has internal data that includes the current position.

Comment: any read/write from/to a file moves the 'virtual'  file pointer by the number of bytes read/written.  The details are kept in the data structure `FILE`.  There is a unique FILE struct in the OS memory for each open file

Comment: Note also that the FILE struct mentioned is the last parameter to `fread`, which in your case is the `source` variable. You would have previously obtained it as the result of a call to `fopen`.

Comment: This is actually a little more complex than what the above comments make it out to be. By default a`FILE` is *buffered*, which means the `fread` call can read more than you request, and store it in a private buffer. The `FILE` structure contains a position in this buffer only. Then the position in the actual file is handled by the operating system, and it has internal buffers and structures. But somewhere down in the operating system, there is a structure member that say "the current position in the file is X".